# How to use Hammer.js plugin with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm using hammer.js plugin library with JavaScript but it throws me error that `target.addEventListener is not a function` in hammer.js file. I tried to look online but couldn't find anything that works with me. Here's my code: 
My template file:

```
<div class="class_name">
 <img src="" class="img_test" />
</div>
```

JavaScript file:

```
var ele = document.getElementByClassName('img_test')
var hammer = new Hammer(ele)
hammer.on('tap', function(){
 console.log('image tapped')
})
```

For certain reasons I'm not using CDN version of this of this plugin, instead I created different file on my local machine and copied code of hammer.js file from GitHub.

And when I run the above code it gives me that `addEventListener` error. I have looked everywhere but couldn't find any solution so, I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

I'm using latest Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using the `.each` function and jQuery.
Solution:

```
$('element').each(function(){
 var mc = new Hammer(this)
 mc.on('tap press', function(e) {
  console.log('type: ', e.type)
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `document.getElementByClassName` isn't correct, but assuming you meant `document.getElementsByClassName`, (note the plural "Elements") then the issue is that this returns an array, even if there is only one element with that class.

so `var hammer = new Hammer(ele[0])` should solve the issue.
And if you do have multiple elements with that class, then you would have to iterate through them in a loop like you did with jQuery.